# Replace gsub to replace fixed string from another dataframe

Tags: r, string, gsub, email-validation

I have a dataframe consisting of multiple unclean email addresses, for example

1) abc@gmailcom
2) def@yahoo.commm
3) fgh@yahoo.coin
4) xyz@gmail

I want to use gsub to clean these emails with the use of another dataframe which will contains patterns and replacements like,

- if pattern found is 'comm' them replace with 'com'
- if pattern found is '.coin' them replace with '.co.in'
- if pattern found is 'gmail' then replace with 'gmail.com' (like in case 4 above,but here I don't want to replace emailids of type abc@gmail.com)

Can someone please suggest a gsub regex.

Comment: `gsub("comm", "com", gsub(".coin", ".co.in", gsub("gmail(?!\\.com)", "gmail.com", theString, perl=TRUE), fixed=TRUE), fixed=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks, this should work for one domains. What if I have multiple domains, like gmail,yahoo and then want to replace @yahoo with yahoo.com?

Will I have to do multiple nesting? 
Or is there any way to have a reference data frame with patterns and replacements and use that in gsub?

Comment: `emails <- c('abc@gmailcom', 'def@yahoo.commm', 'fgh@yahoo.coin', 'xyz@gmail') ; stringr::str_replace_all(emails, c('com+' = 'com', '.coin' = '.co.in', 'gmail\\.?(com)?' = 'gmail.com'))`

Comment: Thanks alistaire. That should work. Just one more thing, in str_replace_all, can I pass a dataframe as second argument for taking care of multiple cases?

Comment: See `?stringr::str_replace_all`, but the short answer is that it has to be a named list where the pattern is the name and the replacement is the element. You can easily construct a suitable list from a data.frame with `setNames`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `list` of patterns and the replacement and use `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
lst <- list(gmailcom = "@gmail.com", yahoo.commm = "@yahoo.com", 
              yahoo.coin = "@yahoo.co.in", gmail = "@gmail.com")
gsubfn("@(.*)", lst , str1)
#[1] "abc@gmail.com"   "def@yahoo.com"   "fgh@yahoo.co.in" "xyz@gmail.com"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("abc@gmailcom", "def@yahoo.commm", "fgh@yahoo.coin", "xyz@gmail")
```